# Getting all active projects in a month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have projects with a `start_date` and an `end_date`. Now I have created a method called `active_projects` which retrieve all projects falling in that specific month. I can call that method with 2 parameters, `month` and `year` like this:

```
def self.active_projects(month, year)
  ...
end
```

This means any project with a part active in a month, is considered as active.
Now let's say I want to get all active projects from february 2014 and I have these 4 projects:

```
project1(start_date: 01-01-2014, end_date: 31-12-2014)
project2(start_date: 01-01-2014, end_date: 15-02-2014)
project3(start_date: 16-02-2014, end_date: 19-02-2014)
project4(start_date: 20-02-2014, end_date: 31-12-2014)
```

Als you can see, only project3 falls completely in this month, the others only partly, but all should be considered as active. How do I get them all with these overlapping start and end_dates?

And you can't just use `Date.today`, because I could also ask this for a month in the past or future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A project is active if its start date is on or before the end of the month, and its end date is on or after the start of the month.

Then:

```
Project.where("start_date <= ? and end_date >= ?",
              Date.new(2013,4,1).end_of_month,
              Date.new(2013,4,1))
```

In scope form, I suppose:

```
scope :active_in_month, ->(year,month){where("start_date <= ? and end_date >= ?",Date.new(year,month,1).end_of_month,Date.new(year,month,1))}
```

Then call:

```
Project.active_in_month(2014,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `where` function from `Model`.

```
Project.where("start_date>= :day_on_month AND start_date<= :day_on_month ", { day_on_month: Time.now })
```